# C++ lock-free thread synchronization

Tags: c++, multithreading, parallel-processing, synchronization, memory-fences

I have following code:

```
bool sync=false;
int* ptr=NULL;
std::thread t([&](){
    do_a(); // long-time operation
    while(!sync){
        std::atomic_thread_fence(std::memory_order_acquire);
    }
    do_b(ptr);
});
int val=do_c();  //long-time operation
ptr=&val;
sync=true;
std::atomic_thread_fence(std::memory_order_release);
....
```

But whet I start this on multiprocessor computer, it sometimes happen, that `do_b()` is started with null pointer. Indon't uneerstand well this behaviour. Does compiler do some optimalizations? Or do I use fences wrong? Does these fences ensure synchronization of data between threads?

Thank you for your tihe and help.

Comment: `sync` has to be atomic to avoid data race. Use `std::atomic<bool> sync{false};` instead.

Comment: What's the use of `sync` here?  Why not just use `ptr` (`while(!ptr)` etc)?

Comment: I suggest using `std::async` instead. It is a lot less error prone. Your (incorrectly) implemented spinlock might even degrade performance

Comment: Also, the fence should be between `ptr=` and `sync=` stores.

Comment: @DanielLangr why `std::atomic`? This is local variable once changed from `false` to `true`. Can something get wrong?

Comment: @DanielLangr can processor store `sync` before storing `ptr` in my case?

Comment: @PasserBy but ste:async is not grant to start separate thread, is it?

Comment: @JohnZwinck this is just simplified code. In my real code, I need `sync`.

Comment: Atomics are __required__ to avoid data races, read about them. `std::async` isn't guaranteed to spawn a new thread, but it will execute on another thread possibly from a thread pool. Again, it is much simpler to use

Comment: @google2 `sync` represents a memory location that is read in one thread and modified in other thread. This is generally data race, if you do not use atomics or synchronize accesses (e.g., via mutexes).

Comment: @google2 Compiler can, processor can, read about compiler reordering, out-of-order execution, store buffers, etc. if you want some details.

Comment: @google2 I would suggest you to start with `std::atomic` and sequentially consistent  memory operations over them. Then, you need no explicit fences.

Comment: @DanielLangr generally, this is data race, I know. But in this case, when `sync` is once set from `false` to `true` is it data race? If there was int and i was using ++ for example, I would have to use atomic. But do I have to here?

Comment: @google2 Generally, it's a data race as well in this particular case. One can argue whether this is data race on a particular hardware architecture, since on x86_64 I believe all loads and stores are atomic automatically under some conditions (such as when you read/write basic data types and they are aligned properly and you don't use SIMD instructions...). But you should better write your program according to the C++ Standard.

Comment: Re, "can processor store sync before storing ptr in my case?"  Unless you are optimizing code for some one-of-a-kind supercomputer, you should not be asking about "my case."  You should be asking what is _[undefined behavior](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub)_ as defined in the C++ language standard, and you should be avoiding it.  That's the only way you can be assured that your program will do the right thing no matter who runs it or, what hardware they run it on.

Answer (score 1):

Your program tries to write the two memory locations (ptr, sync) in that order; but you haven’t told your compiler and or cpu that this is necessary.   Your compiler is free to re-arrange the order of memory writes to suit its goals (winning meaningless benchmarks).   Your cpu is free to re-arrange memory writes to suit its goals (reduced bus contention, meaningless benchmarks).

So, first you should tell your compiler that it is important that it implement the order you desire.   You can accomplish this with the std::atomic, or possibly volatile directives(*).

Secondly, you need to tell your cpu that you are depending upon the visible ordering of these stores.   In a single cpu, the program order (above) and visible order are the same.  In multiple cpus, they not only aren’t necessarily the same, but can vary with current and past system activity.  Thus @DanielLangr’s comment about the fence location.  The fence informs the cpu that all stores preceding the fence must be visible before any stores following the fence.

(*) Benchmark-focussed compiler writers have managed to reduce volatile to near meaninglessness, demonstrating the contempt compiler writers hold for their actual customers.  Oddly, the ‘write those bits in machine language’ has proved to be more maintainable than relying on the artifacts of ‘de jour’ standards writers.   The advent of ‘smart linkers’ may finally neuter systems programming languages in a way that 30 years of standards committees failed to.